# How to use reuse the column value inside the subquery- SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause

I have a sample query -

```
SELECT person_number, 
           result_value, 
           elementname 
    FROM   (SELECT
                   prd.person_number, 
                   dependent.dob, 
                   dependent.person_id ,
                   dependent.payroll_id
            FROM   pay_pay_relationships_dn prd, 
                   (SELECT dependent.person_id, 
                           dependent.dob, 
                           dependent.person_number 
                    FROM   dependent_tab dependent, 
                           pay_payroll_rel_actions pra 
                    WHERE  pra.payroll_relationship_id = 
                           dependent_tab.payroll_relationship_id 
                           AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN dependent.effective_start_date 
                                                      AND 
                                                      dependent.effective_end_date) dependent
                    
            WHERE  dependent.payroll_id = prd.payroll_id 
                   AND prd.effective_date BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date)
```

Is there a way i can use the ppa.effective_date in the subquery - dependent instead of trunc(sysdate)

Comment: where do you define the alias ppa ? Maybe is one of the other already defined ?

Comment: Do you mean `prd.effective_date`?

Comment: Why do you need this? You don't need nested subquery in this query.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov why so ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: hi @GordonLinoff - This is the standard practice at my workplace. I do understand its old syntax and I will change it to new one slow one

Comment: The SQL-90 join syntax is no slower (or faster) than the old syntax; it's just a LOT easier to understand. But this begs the question: why are you posting what I can only take to be work assignments on a public forum? If you did this at my workplace your employment would be in grave danger. (Companies don't like to have their internal software posted publicly. Funny old thing, that...)

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica - These are oracle HCM basic tables and not owned by any company. Its not only for one client... or workplace... hence I do not know why I would be in danger as neither have I disclosed the true IDS nor data

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not define alias `ppa`, so let me assume that you mean `prd.effective_date` instead of `ppa.effective_date`.

If so, then you are describing a lateral join. This is supported in Oracle starting version 12c, using the `LATERAL` or `CROSS/OUTER APPLY` syntax:

```
SELECT 
    person_number, 
    result_value, 
    elementname 
FROM (
    SELECT
        prd.person_number, 
        dep.dob, 
        dep.person_id ,
        dep.payroll_id
    FROM pay_pay_relationships_dn prd
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            dep.person_id, 
            dep.dob, 
            dep.person_number 
        FROM dependent_tab dep
        INNER JOIN pay_payroll_rel_actions pra 
            ON pra.payroll_relationship_id = dep.payroll_relationship_id 
        WHERE 
            dep.payroll_id = prd.payroll_id 
            AND prd.effective_date BETWEEN dep.effective_start_date AND dep.effective_end_date
    ) dep
    WHERE prd.effective_date BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date
) t
```

Note that I also rewrote your implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause) to stanard, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword) - implicit joins are an old syntax from decades ago, that should not be used in new code.

Comment: At least shown query by OP doesn't need laterals/cross apply. And your query will be rewritten by CBO from lateral into inner-joins because of "lateral view decorrelation" transfomation. PS. " implicit joins are an old syntax" - that's basically native Oracle syntax and CBO transforms almost all ANSI explicit joins into own native syntax.